# How to change existing data format through query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have more than 50 000 records in my database, but problem is that contact number is saved with '-' format.

How I can update all records so contact number will be updated without '-'?

[image]

Comment: use an UPDATE statement to replace the - with nothing or a blank space (whatever you need) in all rows. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (And I can't read that tiny image text...)

Comment: @ADyson but my records are in Thousands, so manually one  record  i update? with single query  how it can be updated

Comment: a single UPDATE statement will apply to all the records in the table if you don't specify a WHERE clause. If you didn't know that, you need to do some study into SQL basics

Comment: @ADyson  okay thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE(COLNAME, find_string, replace_with)` in `UPDATE` Statement

```
UPDATE Table_Name
SET CONTACT_NO_1 = REPLACE(CONTACT_NO_1, '-', '')
```

Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0cf5c/1